# modifying from admin panel and logging out does not save the images

Tags: php, html

I have a main pain where I want to modify things from the admin account
and whenever I log out of the admin account the images are not saved and it give me an undefined index error.
this is my main page php code:

```
<?php $src = $_SESSION['firstimgsrc'];echo "<img id='first' src='$src'>";?><!-- Direct link 1st champion -->
        <?php $src1 = $_SESSION['secondimgsrc'];echo "<img id='second' src='$src1'>"; ?><!-- Direct link 2nd champion -->
        <?php $src2 = $_SESSION['thirdimgsrc'];echo "<img id='third' src='$src2'>";?> <!-- Direct link 3rd champion -->
        <?php $src3 = $_SESSION['forthimgsrc'];echo "<img id='forth' style='border-right: 0px;' src='$src3'>"; ?> <!-- Direct link 4th champion -->
```

this is the admin panel php code:

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    session_start();
    $firstimgsrc = $_POST['firstimgsrc'];   
    if ($firstimgsrc == "") {
        $_SESSION['firstimgsrc'] = $jk;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['firstimgsrc'] = $firstimgsrc;
        $jk = $_SESSION['firstimgsrc'];
    }
    $secondimgsrc = $_POST['secondimgsrc'];
    if ($secondimgsrc == "") {
        $_SESSION['secondimgsrc'] = $jk1; } else {
        $_SESSION['secondimgsrc'] = $secondimgsrc;
        $jk1 = $_SESSION['secondimgsrc'];

    }
    $thirdimgsrc = $_POST['thirdimgsrc'];

    if ($thirdimgsrc == "") {
        $_SESSION['thirdimgsrc'] = $jk2;
    } else {
    $_SESSION['thirdimgsrc'] = $thirdimgsrc;
    $jk2 = $_SESSION['thirdimgsrc'];
}
    $forthimgsrc = $_POST['forthimgsrc'];
    if ($forthimgsrc == "") {
        $_SESSION['forthimgsrc'] = $jk3;

    } else {
        $_SESSION['forthimgsrc'] = $forthimgsrc;
        $jk3 = $_SESSION['forthimgsrc'];
    }
    header("Location: ../egamingtv.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: Beware with quotes: Better `echo '<img id="first" src="$src"'>';` than `echo "<img id='first' src='$src'>";`

Comment: i tried what you said but it didn't work.

Comment: I mean i tried it before i even posted this

Comment: Did your *logout* code clears out `$_SESSION` variables? Check this first. Also, make sure you have started session in all of your pages.

Comment: Oh wait the logout stops the sessions, so how do I make session ids

Comment: How do I make it stop a certain session

Answer (score 0):

worked, I just used unset instead of the session_destroy in my logout page